# NodeJS Broadcast channel only working 1 way

Tags: node.js

I have an advanced server controlling multiple APIs and threading wherever possible.

There is 2 main threads, a threadHub * uiThread.

They are using broadcastchannel to communicate.

```js
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('main', {
   type: 'node',
   webWorkerSupport: true
 })
```

The threadHub uses this to get all messages where it sends it to a function that properly processes it.
It succesfully receives all messages send out.

```js
bc.onmessage = (event) => {
    var data = event.data;
    include.threading.getData(data);
};
```

The uiThread uses the same method but never receives any messages not even from self.

```js
bc.onmessage = (event) => {
  var temp = event.data;
  print(`DATA: ${temp}`)// print calls a seperate function where the data is sent to the threadHub which controls STDOUT and logs it. This function does work.
  var buffer = temp.split("|");
  var threadId = buffer[0];
  var dataType = buffer[1];
  var data = buffer[2];
  if (!threadId == "-1") return 1;
  switch (dataType) {
    case "log": {
      debug = debug + data;
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

All messages are sent using `` bc.postMessage(`0|${text}`) ``

BroadcastChannel is defined here:

```js
const {
  Worker, SHARE_ENV, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData, BroadcastChannel
} = require('worker_threads');
```

So my question is why is `bc.onmessage` not working in uiThread but works flawlessly in threadHub?